# Run Silverlight Project...doesn't point to web project

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

I've created a Silverlight app and VS set up a web app for testing automatically. Worked great - whenever I hit "run" it pointed a browser to the web app page which hosted the Silverlight app.

I've done some renaming of the projects, namespaces, files, etc. - just some general clean up. Now when I press "run" on my Silverlight app, it starts up a browser that points to the Silverlight app on disk, rather than pointing it to the test web project that VS set up automatically for me. I've dinked around inside the project settings and can't figure out how to fix this. How do I get it so that when I click "run" on my Silverlight app, the browser is pointed to the web application which references the Silverlight app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this is caused by the StartUp Project for your solution being set to the Silverlight application itself, rather than the Web project.
To fix this, right-click on the Web app in Solution Explorer and click on "Set as StartUp Project". 
Also, right-click on your *.aspx or *.html file within your Web project and click "Set As Start Page".
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps anyone:

I encountered the same problem, and the above method unfortunately didn't work for me.

Here's what I did: I unchecked 'Generate app manifest' from the project settings, and ticking it and rebuilding solved my problem.